# Why are some packages missing when I run yarn install?

Tags: webpack, npm-install, yarnpkg

I am trying to migrate my web app from npm to Yarn.  When I run `yarn install --production` it completes successfully.  However when I start it using `node webpack.js` it tells me:

```
ERROR in Cannot find module 'lodash._isiterateecall'

ERROR in Cannot find module 'has'
```

These two projects aren't in the node_modules folder, but they are listed as dependencies in the `yarn.lock` file.

Anyone got any ideas why? Is this a bug in Yarn?

I am using yarn 0.17.2 and npm 2.15.9

Comment: Problem is fixed when I just use yarn install, I was using yarn install --production before

Answer (score 5):

Is this a bug in Yarn? Yes checkout below link  [yarn install --production` doesn't install correct dependencies](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/761)

Try to do follow the steps . Can you do a yarn cache clean and try again?

```
npm ls entities after yarn --prod

yarn check --prodution --verify-tree
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something to do, called integrity check. 
If you run `yarn check` it correctly notes the missing dependency. But when you simply `yarn / yarn install`, it assumes all is well. Delete yarn.integrity and it obviously rebuilds.

What we need is for yarn install to automatically do an integrity check. If the check fails, it should rebuild.

`yarn install --skip-integrity-check` seems to actually do the trick

Answer (score 1):

with me, i fixed the issue with

```
yarn install --network-concurrency 1
```